# Concatenate two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two text columns A and B. I want to take the first non empty string or if both A and B has values take the values from A. C is the column im trying to create:

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['A','B']
data = [['data','data'],
        ['','data'],
        ['',''],
        ['data1','data2']]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=data, columns=cols)

      A      B
0  data   data
1         data
2             
3  data1  data2
```

My attempt:

```
df['C'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row: sorted([val if val else '' for val in row], reverse=True)[0], axis=1) #Reverse sort to avoid picking an empty string

      A      B      C
0  data   data      data
1         data      data
2             
3  data1  data2     data2 #I want data1 here
```

Expected output:

```
      A      B      C
0  data   data      data
1         data      data
2             
3  data1  data2     data1
```

I think I want the pandas equivalent of SQL coalesce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [1022]: import numpy as np
In [1023]: df['C'] = np.where(df['A'].eq(''), df['B'], df['A'])

In [1024]: df
Out[1024]: 
       A      B      C
0   data   data   data
1          data   data
2                     
3  data1  data2  data1
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's try `idxmax` + `lookup`:

```
df['C'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.ne('').idxmax(1))
```

Alternatively you can use `Series.where`:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].where(lambda x: x.ne(''), df['B'])
```

---

```
       A      B      C
0   data   data   data
1          data   data
2                     
3  data1  data2  data1
```